# Issues formatting a new file in python

Tags: python, file-processing, script-debugging

So I am pretty new to python ( and coding in general ) and I could use some serious help finding the problem in my code.
   Basically, I am opening a file that contains any number of students name followed 4 test scores. So Something like this:

```
John
78.0
80.0
69.0
98.0
Bob
40.0
78.0
77.0
89.0
etc
```

My program is suppose to then read said file and out put to the shell:

```
  John: 78.0 80.0 69.0 98.0 Average: 81.25
  Bob: 40.0 78.0 77.0 89.0 Average: 71.0
```

And finally it should save the names and averages to a new file like,

```
  John,81.25
  Bob, 71.0
```

However my program prints this to the screen:

```
Mary
 :76.0 89.0 82.0 100.0 Average: 86.75
Joey
 :91.0 81.0 83.0 95.0 Average: 87.5
Sally
 :92.0 93.0 90.0 97.0 Average: 93.0
```

And is saving files like this:

```
  Mary
  86.75Joey
  87.5Sally
  93.0
```

Can anyone help with either of these issues? Its a school assignment so just help identifying my bad coding would be sufficient.

Here is my mess of a code:

## Create file containing students scores

```
scoresa = open('project3-scoresa.txt','w')
scoresa.write("Mary\n76\n89\n82\n100\nJoey\n91\n81\n83\n95\nSally\n92\n93\n90\n97")
scoresa.close()



def main():
    averages = open("averages.csv","w")
    file = input("Please enter the scores filename:")
    try:
        scores = open(file,'r')
        print("File",file,"has been opened")
    except IOError:
        print("File",file,"could not be opened.")
    scores = open(file,'r')
    i = 0
    for line in scores:
        if i%5 == 0:
            name = line
            print(name.strip("/n"),":", end="")
            j = 1
            total = 0
        else:
            score = float(line)
            print(score, end=" ")
            total += score
            ave = total/j
            if j == 4:
                print("Average:",ave)
                Avestring = (name + str(ave))
                averages.write(Avestring)
            j += 1
        i += 1
    scores.close()
    averages.close()
    average = open("averages.csv","r")
    for line in average:
        print(line.strip("\n"))
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Try this.

```
def main():
    averages = open("averages.csv","w")
    file = input("Please enter the scores filename:")
    try:
        scores = open(file,'r')
        print("File",file,"has been opened")
    except IOError:
        print("File",file,"could not be opened.")
    scores = open(file,'r')
    i = 0
    for line in scores:
        if i%5 == 0:
            name = line.strip("\n")
            print(name,":", end="")
            j = 1
            total = 0
        else:
            score = float(line)
            print(score, end=" ")
            total += score
            ave = total/j
            if j == 4:
                print("Average:",ave)
                Avestring = (name + "," + str(ave) + "\n")
                averages.write(Avestring)
            j += 1
        i += 1
    scores.close()
    averages.close()
    average = open("averages.csv","r")
    for line in average:
        print(line.strip("\n"))
main()
```

Main changes are:

```
name = line.strip("\n") # note the \n not /n
print(name,":", end="")

Avestring = (name + "," + str(ave) + "\n") # note the comma and line break.
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a big help.

Comment: Do you need any more advice before you accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line:

```
print(name.strip("/n"),":", end="")
```

i.e. you should have `\n` (the escape sequence indicating a new line character), not `/n`

This means that the newline character is not removed from the name when printing, which is why you have output like this:

```
Mary
 :76.0 89.0 82.0 100.0 Average: 86.75
```

rather than this:

```
Mary:76.0 89.0 82.0 100.0 Average: 86.75
```

(note you also need to add a space after the `:` to get your target output)

Note that even if you had used `name.strip('\n')` (i.e. without the typo), that you would still see the second problem when writing to file. Calling `strip()` on `name` doesn't alter the value of `name` itself, so the newline character is still in `name` when you do:

```
Avestring = (name + str(ave))
averages.write(Avestring)
```

To update the value of `name` you would do:

```
name = name.split('\n')
```

which takes the old value of `name`, calls `split()` on it and stores the returned result back into `name`.

However, in this case, you could simply do:

```
name = line.split('\n')
```

since you never need the name with the newline character included, so may as well remove it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem can be solved by replacing  "/n" by  "\n" in the line no 20:

```
 print(name.strip("/n"),":", end="")
```

and this will turn to :

```
 print(name.strip("\n"),":", end="")
```

And the other changes that i made were in line no  : 19 and 30 . I first sripped the string for the new line character . The new line of code will be .

```
name = line.strip("\n")
Avestring = (name +","+ str(ave)+ "\n")
```